# How can I get nth child in array of items retrieved by class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few `<a>` elements with the class `brandPagination`

If I use this:

```
console.log($j('.brandPagination'));
```

I get an array with five items in it. I want the nth one. So I tried:

```
console.log($j('.brandPagination:nth-of-type(1)'));
```

This outputs an empty array, why and what can I do about it?

Comment: Did you try the pseudo `$j('.brandPagination:eq(xx)')` or `$j('.brandPagination').eq(xx)`?

Comment: Did you try giving `:eq(1)` a go?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1vpqee5z/1/

Comment: Kristofer, kan you add your HTML here or a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use

```
$j('.brandPagination:eq(0)');
// or 
$j('.brandPagination').eq(0);
```

Keep in mind `nth-of-type` starts in 1, and jQuery's `eq` is zero based.

Answer (score -1):

Use the last-child selector to fetch the last item of the selector specified before.

Try this out,

```
console.log($j('.brandPagination:last-child'));
```